# Malformed axios request after POSTing body with Buffer from pdf file

Tags: node.js, axios, multipartform-data

I am writing node.js aws lambda. I am getting base64 encoded body of multipart/form-data from another aws lambda, then i am parsing it using parse-multipart-data, doing some validation, and then using form-data to create a bit different multipart/form-data body and use axios to POST it to Salesforce api.

The problem is that when i append Buffer of pdf file to form and try to send request with that form as body, it malforms whole body, instead of looking normally it is an 8k chars string (not sure what that is tbh) when i check outgoing body through nock, when testing it through mockbin i get internal server error in requests history, when deployed on dev aws environment connected to dev salesforce environment and testing it i get 503 after timeout.

It is quite bizarre since when i append even a large buffer through `new Buffer(10000)` to form it works fine. No idea how this buffer is different than the one from pdf file.

I did a lot of googling and trial and error on it but i haven't found anything, but here are also some other facts i noticed off the top of my head:

- body is being malformed only in outgoing request, checking form beforehand shows correct body
- using jpeg file also breaks request body
- using .txt file works fine (prints correct multipart/form-data body in mockbin and when unit testing)
- using other parsers or axios alternatives didn't help
- using Buffer from file in request other than multipart/form-data seem to also malform body same way when not encapsulated for example in json object
- tried using filestream of local file thats same as one being send to me, same result
- using workbench to manually create some multipart/formdata request to salesforce works fine

Comment: It would help if you post the code that prepares and sends the request.